# compiling error magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, setup-di-compile

I am using Magento 2.4.5 and php 8.1

when I try to  sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

I get this error:

```
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% 1 sec 119.0 MiBUnclosed '{' on line 23#0 /var/www/magento2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#2 /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists()
#3 /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#4 /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#5 /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#6 /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#7 /var/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()
#8 /var/www/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()
#9 /var/www/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#10 /var/www/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#11 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#12 /var/www/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#13 /var/www/magento2/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

I checked the debug log and system logs and nothing there. How do I debug this?
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can find in which class you have an issue using the below file path.

```
<MagentoRoot>/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php
```

> Add the below line in the getList() function.

```
echo "Class: ".$path."\n"
```

[image]

> After adding please run php bin/magento setup:di:compile command. you can see the class path. once you found and fix it please remove that line.

Comment: Thanks Msquare: My last path is Class: /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search
Unclosed '{' on line 23#0 /var/www/magento2/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(432): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::Composer\Autoload\{closure}().  Where Do I remove the path line?

Comment: @Henri Once you got the class then undo your changes from the above mention file path and Removed echo from it. and check compilation again.

Comment: Hi Msquare. Thx for your help. My question is where do I know where to fix the class? It says there is an Unclosed '{' on line 23 but it does not tell me where I should fix the class.

Comment: @Henri Can you connect with me on skype? https://join.skype.com/invite/nkVHQ28bB2M6

Comment: Many thanks Msquare I was able to find the right class in my vendor directory and correct the mistake.